# Updating a single column in a table for some certain range of rows using django form

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an application with a model verification. I get data from user in this model with one null column. I want to update that particular null column later. I want to update the column for a range of records(subset of table).

I am using the code bellow:

models.py

```
class Verification(models.Model):
asset_code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Asset Code",max_length=16, default="")
scan_time=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Time of smartDNA scan",auto_now_add=True,default=datetime.datetime.now)
credential = models.CharField(verbose_name="smartDNA Credential",max_length=16, 
operator = models.CharField(verbose_name="Operator",max_length=16, default="")
location = models.CharField(verbose_name="Branch",max_length=64, default="")
auth_code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Scanner Authentication",max_length=20, default="DSC(Verisign")
emp_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="EMP ID",max_length=16, default="")
image = models.CharField(verbose_name="Image",max_length=24, default="dd")
created=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Created on",blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
modified=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Modified on",blank=True,auto_now=True)
product_details= models.CharField(verbose_name="Product Details",max_length=64, default="")
```

views.py

```
    def update_details(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
    if 'search' in request.POST:
            form = UpdateDetailsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
               fr=form.cleaned_data['asset_code1']
               to=form.cleaned_data['asset_code2']
               verifications = Verification.objects.filter(asset_code__range=(fr,to))
               verifications.update(product_details=form.cleaned_data['product_details'])
   return render_to_response('update_details.html',
                {'form':UpdateDetailsForm(),},
                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    asset_code1 = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    asset_code2 = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    product_details = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I want to update all "product_details" column with form data submitted by user for a range of "asset_code". And both product_details and asset_code range is provided by user form.

but this code is not working. Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database sort and collation settings give you the ordering you're expecting, you can use `__gte` and `__lte` or `__gt` and `__lt` on your field:

```
verifications = Verification.objects.filter(asset_code__gte=fr, asset_code__lte=to)
```

Typically that'll do a lexical ordering, so that 'aaaa' comes before 'aaab' etc, but the exact details depend on your database settings.